# Defining a custom rails route with query parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a `/articles` page that I can access via the `articles_path` route helper.

Let's say I have 2 tabs on that page (e.g. [something like this](http://html5beginners.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/jquery-tab.jpg)) that the user can click back and forth on, but it doesn't leave the page.

I have logic that allows the user to deep link to a specific tab, so either of the following url's are valid and will open the page on the specified tab directly.

- `/articles?tab=foo`
- `/articles?tab=bar`

Is it possible to define two new custom routes with the above urls that include the query parameter? I'd love to have a helper like `articles_foo_tab_path` and `articles_bar_tab_path` that incorporate those query parameters directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create those helper methods:

```
module ArticlesHelper
  def articles_foo_tab_path(article)
    article_path(article, tab: 'foo')
  end

  def articles_foo_bar_path(article)
    article_path(article, tab: 'bar')
  end
end
```

And use them in your views:

```
<%= link_to @article.title, articles_foo_bar_path(@article) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The helper method is one solution. Alternatively you can add a route which maps the tab param to the url e.g. articles/foo or articles/bar

```
get "articles(filter/:filter)", to: "articles#index", filter: /.*/
```